# Input type="time" format issue

Tags: html, css

So I am using default time picker of HTML

```
<input type="time" />
```

Now my problem is in some system it is coming as 12HR format and in some system as 24HR format.

Is there any solution for this so that I can fix this as 12HR format?

Comment: If the user is more comfortable using 24 hours, why would you want to change that? The `value` is always in 24 hour format regardless of what is displayed to the user.

Comment: It's a request from the client to fix it as 12 HR

Comment: Well, sorry, but that requires some custom time picker. The format presented to the user in the native time inputs is an OS preference. I wouldn't suggest going against it, because some users may get confused while using other format. Do you have any idea about why the client would want that? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: What is displayed doesn't matter. The browser will always send it in 24-hour format.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time I think the only solution is to create a custom time picker as @D.Pardal mentioned.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes I know that, but what is shown that does matter also

Comment: I found out that whatever format is chosen in the system time input type="time" takes that only, it cannot be further customized

Comment: @D.Pardal Actually the user of that software are more comfortable with the 12 hr format

Comment: @harshitverma Then tell the user to change its OS's settings. It's easier that way.